# Why does getActivity of my fragment returns null?

Tags: android, android-activity, null

I currently have a thread in my main Activity do download stuff frow web and I then need to update the Fragments inside a ViewPager after download finished.

The download is handled by a service and broadcast an Intent when finished.

So, basically, my code in my main Activity is:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ((PositionFragment)mPagerAdapter.getItem(0)).updateUI();
    }
}
```

and my PositionFragment:

```
public void updateUI() {
    mActivity = getActivity();
```

I really don't get how this can be null. This really souds simple, but I must be missing something!

Any idea?

Edit: my Adapter:

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles[position];
    }
}
```

Comment: As you can see in my Adapter, the getItem returns the created Fragment that exists!

Comment: It always happens, I have set a code in the onResume of the Fragment to broadcast the Intent it if data is too old. So the Activity+Fragment have just been set in background and then resumed

Comment: `getActivity()` is returning null because the fragment did not get attached to the Activity yet. Where are you calling `updateUI()`? In `onCreateView()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getActivity() returns null in Fragment function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215239/getactivity-returns-null-in-fragment-function)

Comment: Look for [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27678112/1252158), it might help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your fragment has probably been detached from the activity. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536166/android-get-activity-returns-null) for more details.

Comment: Sound like a start, but how should I access the Fragment in the Adapter with FragmentManager, like suggested in the answer.. I will try this other solution that looks nice: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15261142/327402

Answer (score 0):

You can call `getActivity()` only after fragment's `onAttach` method is called. I believe, that's the issue here.

Comment: This code is called after the onResume, so I strongly belive that onAttach was called before ;-)