# getActivity() gives context equal to null

Tags: android, android-fragments, constructor, android-context

I have developed and launched an Android application. It works fine on my Android phone, but it crashes on several devices.

```
*BugSense gives me the following error:*
0   java.lang.NullPointerException

1   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)

2   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.(ArrayAdapter.java:128)

3   **at com.challenger.app.ChallengeAdapter.(ChallengeAdapter.java:27)**

4   at com.challenger.app.AllChallenges.fitChallenges(AllChallenges.java:142)

5   at com.challenger.app.AllChallenges$1.onSuccess(AllChallenges.java:108)



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler;
    import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

    public class AllChallenges extends Fragment {


    Button loginButton;
    ListView listView2, listView1;

    TextView textView;
    int category = 0;
    View view;
    List<Challenge> challenge_data;

    public AllChallenges(int cat) {
        category = cat;
    }

    public AllChallenges() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if(getActivity()!=null){
            load();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.allchallenges, container, false);

        if(getActivity()!=null){
            load();
        }

        return view;
    }

    public void load() {
        loadOld();

        if (!AppSettings.refreshed[category + 1]) {
            update();
        }

    }

    public void loadOld() {

        Log.d("Challenge", "Updating " + category);
        JSONArray a = AppSettings.loadChallenges(category, getActivity());
        if (a != null) {

            fitChallenges(makeArray(a));
        }

    }

    public void update() {
        Log.d("Challenge", "getChallenges/" + category);
        RequestParams a = new RequestParams();
        if (AppSettings.logged) {
            a.put("fb_id", AppSettings.facebookId);
            a.put("fb_authkey", AppSettings.facebookAuthToken);
        }
        NetworkClient.receiveJSON("getChallenges/" + category, a,
                new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(JSONArray chalList) {
                        Log.d("Challenge", "Downloaded " + category);
                        AppSettings.saveChallenges(category, chalList,
                                getActivity());
                        fitChallenges(makeArray(chalList));
                        AppSettings.refreshed[category + 1] = true;
                    }
                });

    }

    public Challenge[] makeArray(JSONArray list) {
        challenge_data = new ArrayList<Challenge>();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject chal = (JSONObject) list.get(i);
                String[] arr = {};
                if (chal.has("friends"))
                    arr = JSONArrToArr(chal.getJSONArray("friends"));

                Log.e("Boolean", chal.getString("active"));

                challenge_data.add(new Challenge(chal.getInt("id"), chal
                        .getString("title"), chal.getInt("category"), chal
                        .getInt("taken_by"), arr, chal.getBoolean("active"),
                        chal.getString("text"), chal.getInt("streak"), chal
                                .getInt("percentage")));

            }
            return challenge_data.toArray(new Challenge[challenge_data.size()]);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void fitChallenges(Challenge[] chalArray) {
        **ChallengeAdapter adapter = new ChallengeAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_row, chalArray);** //
        listView1 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

        OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Log.i("listener", "am ID" + id + "position " + position);
                int n = (int) id;
                String title = challenge_data.get(n).toStringArray()[1];
                Log.i("listener", "am ID" + id + "position " + position
                        + "  title " + title);
                int people = challenge_data.get(n).peopleInt;
                String category = challenge_data.get(n).toStringArray()[0];
                String description = challenge_data.get(n).toStringArray()[5];
                int streak = challenge_data.get(n).streak;
                int percentage = challenge_data.get(n).percentage;
                int chal_id = challenge_data.get(n).id;
                boolean active = challenge_data.get(n).active;

                ((AllChallengesPager) getActivity()).showDetailed(chal_id,
                        title, "" + people, category, active, description, ""
                                + streak, "" + percentage);
            }
        };

        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(listener);

    }

    public String[] JSONArrToArr(JSONArray arr) {
        String[] newArr = {};
        try {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

                list.add(arr.getString(i));

            }
            newArr = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return newArr;
    }}

public class ChallengeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Challenge> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    Challenge data[] = null;
    Typeface a;

    public ChallengeAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            Challenge[] data) {

        **super(context, layoutResourceId, data);** //in this line code crashes

        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        a = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                "fonts/roboto_condensed.ttf");

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ChallengeHolder holder = null;

        Challenge challenge = data[position];

        if (row == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ChallengeHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.challenge);
            holder.txtPeople = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.peopleNumber);
            holder.friendThumbs = (LinearLayout) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.friendThumbs);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ChallengeHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        holder.friendThumbs.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < challenge.friendIds.length; i++) {
            holder.friendThumbs.addView(createIcon(challenge.friendIds[i],
                    context));
        }

        holder.txtTitle.setText(challenge.title);
        holder.txtTitle.setTypeface(a);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(challenge.icon);
        holder.txtPeople.setText(challenge.peopleString);

        return row;
    }

    static class ChallengeHolder {
        public LinearLayout friendThumbs;
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtPeople;

    }

    public ImageView createIcon(String friendID, Context cont) {
        ImageView icon = new ImageView(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams par = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                (int) cont.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.fbIconSize),
                (int) cont.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.fbIconSize));
        par.setMargins(0, 0, 15, 0);
        icon.setLayoutParams(par);

        Log.e("ID " + friendID, "log");

        final String myurl = AppSettings.profilePictureUrl(friendID);
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_fb_icon_small);
        ((MyApplication) ((Activity) context).getApplication())
                .loadImageSimple(myurl, icon);

        return icon;

    }
}
```

*I guess that the cause of this problem is context equal to null got from the method getActivity, but don't know how to deal with this problem. Could anyone explain how to solve the problem?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your Fragment is detached from your activity at this stage as this is called in an external thread JsonHttpResponseHandler.

You have a good explanation here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11536337/891479

Answer (score 1):

I think onActivityCreated method override and implement for this code, and its working fine may be...

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if(getActivity()!=null){
        load();
    }
}
```

And Fragment lifecyle must read for this doc [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated)

Answer (score 0):

You should not call

```
if(getActivity()!=null){
     load();
}
```

in `onCreateView`.

---

`onViewCreated` is called after `onCreateView` and as per the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated)

> The fragment's view hierarchy is not however attached to its parent
>   at this point.

Answer (score -1):

I think if I remember correctly its better to use `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`