# getActivity() had returned null when isDetached() had returned false

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

Once upon a time my debugger hit the breakpoint on Log.d:

```
@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataTypeChanged dataType) {
    if (!isDetached()) {
        if(getActivity()==null){
            Log.d(CommonConstants.DEBUG_TAG, "Yes, it is null.");
        }
        List<WeekViewCoreTask> tasks = DataProvider
                .getWeekViewCoreTasks(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        mWeekView.setTasks(tasks);
    }
}
```

[image: getActivity() returns null when isDetached() returns false]

I thought this never could occur. How this could occur: getActivity() had returned null when isDetached() had returned false?

Comment: Hi sergey you are extends your application from Activity or Fragment.Please let me know. If your extends your application from Activity means you will call getBaseActivity() instead of getActivity().getApplicationContext(). If you extends your application from Fragment means your will use getActivity() instead of getActivity().getApplicationContext(). Hope it should helpful for you. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536166/android-get-activity-returns-null check this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not 100% sure on this, but according to the Android docs, [isDetached()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isDetached%28%29) will only return true if a `Fragment` has been explicitly detached from its `Activity`. There are several other reasons a `Fragment`'s parent Activity could be null, though. It might be best to instead call `isAdded` to check if the `Fragment` is currently attach to its `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

According to the Android docs, `isDetached()`

> Return true if the fragment has been explicitly detached from the UI. That is, FragmentTransaction.detach(Fragment) has been used on it.

which means `isDetached()` represents the **UI** status, it has nothing to do with the attachment to its `Activity`.

A `Fragment` will be detached from its `Activity` only after `onDetach()` method is called. At that point, `isDetached()` can both be `true` or `false` depending on whether `FragmentTransaction.detach(Fragment)` has been used on the fragment.