# Null pointer exception while getting path of image in android

Tags: android, image

I am getting null pointer exception while getting path from following method.

```
String path=Utils.getPath(getActivity(), Uri.parse(/storage/emulated/0/1421835338859.jpg
 ));

   @SuppressLint("NewApi") public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }

                // TODO handle non-primary volumes
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                        split[1]
                };

                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: on witch version ? all device or just newer than kitkat , or older than kitkat?

Comment: I am testing on 4.4.4 kitkat. I have checked on other device too.issue is exist on other too.

Comment: Uri.parse(/storage/emulated/0/1421835338859.jpg
 )); is it correct ?

Comment: try use Paul Burke's answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067508/get-real-path-from-uri-android-kitkat-new-storage-access-framework , i've use that and it's work fine, if your code is same check path is correct or not

Answer (score 0):

```
String path=Utils.getPath(getActivity(), Uri.parse(/storage/emulated/0/1421835338859.jpg
 ));
```

From how it is posted in the question, if you are calling that outside `onCreate()` or any other method, `getActivity()` is null, read [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) and [why it happens with fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536166/android-get-activity-returns-null)