# Calling Activity from Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a problem with calling activity from fragment class. More:

XML of adapter's layout:

```
<TextView
     style="@style/LiHeadLogin"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:onClick="openProfile"
     android:id="@+id/genFrom" />
```

Code from main activity that calls fragment:

```
public void openProfile(View v) {
     Fragment_Questions frau = new Fragment_Questions();
     frau.openProfile(v);
}
```

Code from fragment class:

```
public void openProfile(View v) {

    View row = (View) v.getParent();

    TextView child2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.genFromlogin);
    String child3 = child2.getText().toString();

    Intent ini = getActivity().getIntent();
    String c_username = ini.getStringExtra(MainActivity.KEY_USERNAME);
    String c_password = ini.getStringExtra(MainActivity.KEY_PASSWORD);
    Intent ini2 = new Intent(context, User.class);
    ini2.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_USERNAME, c_username);
    ini2.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_PASSWORD, c_password);
    ini2.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_USER, child3);
    getActivity().startActivity(ini2);

}
```

Errors:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
...
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Intent android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getIntent()' on a null object reference
```

P.S.
1. App opens default activity
2. User calls a new activity with passing intent data
3. New activity calls fragment

The first (main) activity:

```
Intent intent_settings = getIntent();
            String c_username = intent_settings.getStringExtra(MainActivity.KEY_USERNAME);
            String c_password = intent_settings.getStringExtra(MainActivity.KEY_PASSWORD);
            Intent intent_settings_1 = new Intent(this, NewFeed.class);
            intent_settings_1.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_USERNAME, c_username);
            intent_settings_1.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_PASSWORD, c_password);
            intent_settings_1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            startActivity(intent_settings_1);
```

Okay, and you should know that all fragments are called by viewpager with tab layout.

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Fragment_Home tab1 = new Fragment_Home();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Fragment_Questions tab2 = new Fragment_Questions();
                return tab2;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: will you add the intent that putStringExtra

Comment: @DasserBasyouni yes, I've added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access the activity with `getActivity()` between calls to `onAttach()` and `onDetach()`.

`Fragment_Questions` itself only seems to serve the purpose to start a new activity, so you could just move all the logic to the click listener of the activity and don't use the fragment at all.

If there's more about the fragment and you're actually planning to add it to the activity sometime in the future it still seems better to have this logic separated from the fragment. You only use `getActivity()` and magically `context` in there. You could just make it static and give the activity as parameter instead.

```
public static void openProfile(Activity activity, View v) {
    View row = (View) v.getParent();

    TextView child2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.genFromlogin);
    String child3 = child2.getText().toString();

    Intent ini = activity.getIntent();
    String c_username = ini.getStringExtra(MainActivity.KEY_USERNAME);
    String c_password = ini.getStringExtra(MainActivity.KEY_PASSWORD);
    Intent ini2 = new Intent(activity, User.class);
    ini2.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_USERNAME, c_username);
    ini2.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_PASSWORD, c_password);
    ini2.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_USER, child3);
    activity.startActivity(ini2);
}
```

Comment: should you please add some code how to realise it, I've tried, but unsuccessful.

Comment: I made it!! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Do you extends Fragment OR FragmetnActivity?

if you extend FragmetnActivity (as i think) then dont use getActivity()

Also add the code for the intent that started your current activity

```html
 Fragment_Questions frau = new Fragment_Questions();
     frau.openProfile(v);
```

You just created new fragment you didnt attached it to the activity?
use FragmentManager.

if you trying to use fragment inside ViewPager use [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536166/android-get-activity-returns-null) guide

Comment: I use just Fragment

Comment: upload the code that you started your current activity with

Comment: I use viewpager with tab layout to call fragment

Comment: I would love to help you bro but you give us only small parts of code, we need to see how your layout and entire fragment looks like or we will just keep guessing.

Comment: I know thats what I told you. You are making NEW fragment which is NOT attached to the activity, therefor getActivity()= null

Comment: So, bro, main activity calls method openProfile inside fragment successfully. Problem is located where calling new intent

Comment: I KNOW its called succefully. but once against getActivity() returns null object. The reason is that the fragment isnt attached to the activity.

Comment: So how I must attach it?

Comment: well you said you use viewpager, is the fragment in the viewpager?
i will add to the answer link to a related topic

Comment: Read the post i linked to in the last line in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should add Fragment_Questions to Activity.

For example,In Activity layout:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <fragment
         android:id="@+id/fragment_question"
         android:name="com.example.view.Fragment_Questions"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

In Acitivity.java:

```
questionFragment = (Fragment_Questions) findViewById(fragment_question);
```

and then, you can user OnClick Event like this:

```
questionFragment.openProfile(v);
```

Comment: I use viewpager with tab layout to call fragment

Comment: Function is calling successfully, problem is inside the method that calls activity

Comment: have you init the ViewPager at Activity? you should give more detail code.

Comment: yes, I've inited, I've added more code to my question

Answer (score 0):

You are getting Null Pointer Exception because your fragment is not attached to Activity. You are just instantiating the fragment and then calling its openProfile(View v) method which is a wrong way to handle events. If you already attached fragment then get the instance of framgent using

```
questionFragment = (Fragment_Questions) findViewById(fragment_question);
```

You can read below article on how to communicate from Fragments to activity
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: I use viewpager with tab layout to call fragment

Comment: Function is calling successfully, problem is inside the method that calls activity

Answer (score 0):

As I have understanded the steps of the user interferance you have to replace `getIntent()` in the fragment with the intent that starts it which is `intent_settings` i think

Also make the that intent `static` in order to share it

And make if statment in order not to have null exception

```
if(theIntent.hasPutextra)
{getExtra.....}
```